# How to get records based on most occurring value?

Tags: oracle

I have following table and I want to get records where promotion is mostly occurring.

For example if I got two events

1. FREQ_VISITOR, value= 250
2. HIGH_SHOPPER, value= 320

Then Promo 1 and Promo 2 should come in result. Since these 2 promos exists mostly for every trigger and their given values.

[image]

Comment: Please **edit your question** and provide a sample of the output you're looking for, based on the data you've provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, based on what I understood:

```
SQL> with test (event_name, value, promotion) as
  2    (select 'freq_visitor', 250, 'promo1' from dual union all
  3     select 'high_shopper', 320, 'promo2' from dual union all
  4     select 'freq_visitor', 250, 'promo3' from dual union all
  5     select 'high_shopper', 320, 'promo1' from dual union all
  6     select 'freq_visitor', 250, 'promo2' from dual
  7    ),
  8  cnt_promo as
  9    (select promotion, count(*) cnt
 10     from test
 11     group by promotion
 12    ),
 13  most_promos as
 14    (select max(cnt) max_cnt
 15     from cnt_promo
 16    )
 17  select c.promotion
 18  from cnt_promo c join most_promos m on c.cnt = m.max_cnt;

PROMOT
------
promo1
promo2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good candidate for analytic functions.

The below code is a bit longer than the self-join approach, and flows from the inside-out instead of a more traditional top-to-bottom direction.  But this approach will likely be faster, since it only reads from the table once.  And this approach is easier to debug than common table expressions, since you can highlight and run different inline views and watch the result set be built.

```
--Promotions with the highest counts.
select promotion
from
(
    --RANK the promotion counts.
    select promotion, promotion_count,
        rank() over (order by promotion_count desc) promotion_rank
    from
    (
        --Count of promos per event and value.
        select promotion, count(*) promotion_count
        from
        (
            --Test data
            select 'freq_visitor' event_name, 250 value, 'promo1' promotion from dual union all
            select 'high_shopper' event_name, 320 value, 'promo2' promotion from dual union all
            select 'freq_visitor' event_name, 250 value, 'promo3' promotion from dual union all
            select 'high_shopper' event_name, 320 value, 'promo1' promotion from dual union all
            select 'freq_visitor' event_name, 250 value, 'promo2' promotion from dual
        ) test_data
        group by promotion
    ) add_promo_count
) add_promo_rank
where promotion_rank = 1
order by promotion;
```